# How to make a wall jump in Unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a script to rebound from the ball like a Super Meat Boy.

For normal jump, the script code is:

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
```

How to make a second script to bounce off the wall?

[image]

I just need one line of code to jump.
When I try to edit the above code to bounce off the walls, my character teleports, instead of smoothly move to the left.
I do not understand why teleports. When I tell my hero to just jump up, then jump normally, and when I tell him to jump to the left, it is the effect of teleportation.

[image]

Comment: "When I try to edit the above code" What exactly are you doing? The script you have posted just adds a force in y-Direction (upwards) and you obviously want to do something else as well if you want to bounce of a wall

Comment: I've displayed the images in the question. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @UnholySheep but when Im trying for example (just left) -> rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(-10 * Force, 0));  then my hero will make teleport instead smooth jump :(, when i use X and Y then same effect, left side jump = teleport. I want to make slowly left jump/normal jump, not teleport in 0,00001 sec.

Comment: If I read your values correctly then you are adding a force of 7000(!) (-10*700, according to the screenshot) which is gigantic. You should definitely use some smaller values. You will probably also want to have a bit of upwards force (you will have to try out values though)

Comment: @UnholySheep when I use force 10 then my hero will move 2 pixels maybe! When i use 7000 then my hero will move 1 cm or 2 cm. So what to do to move 2 cm to left if i cant use high value? I dont understand why Y jump force 700 is okay, but when i try use same value for X (left side) then this value is super hiper small and my hero will move to left some pixels instead 1-2 cm

Comment: That amount of options between 10 and 7000 is still more than enough for experimentation. You should also use two separate variables for Upward Force and Sideways force, in order to be able to tune them separately. However with this code no teleportation is taking place, so if that is still occurring you either have a too big force or something else is wrong

Comment: @UnholySheep check this out :D http://i.imgur.com/sLKGHir.png and left jump movement = always instant teleport

Comment: Well, I can't help you then - obviously something is wrong with your scripts, but the amount of information you provide is not sufficient to help you. I do not know where your scripts are attached or when you call which function, ergo I cannot even begin to play debugger for you. Also if you provide more information you should edit that into your question, so other may be able to read that as well

Comment: @UnholySheep ok, so there is all code http://pastebin.com/s7f5zS3a (btw. and both jump codes [update and fixed update] same effect to left jump, i mean, when i put -X value to both jump codes = both codes will instantly teleport my hero)

Comment: @UnholySheep you got script, and now you will get screenshot -> http://i.imgur.com/KwD95vY.png I hope, it can help a little? I just use one script for my player. I dont have more than 1 scripts.

Comment: @UnholySheep probably I found the problem -> when i "comment" this line (movement line) -> rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (h * speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y); then my hero jump normally lol